# Magento 2 : Add custom text in payment step of checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, knockoutjs

I have a requirement like below.

If there aren't any payment methods, There is a text showing in payment page

**No Payment method available.**

under the path

> Magento_Checkout\web\template\payment.html

My requirement here is to include a link after the text like below

`No Payment method available.` **click here** to edit address. ==> It should be linked to customer account page

How can this be achieved, I am not so good in `knockout.js` to bind the links in html pages.

Please can anyone help me implement this functionality? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, To update message in checkout payment step you need to update **payment.html** file and then, to pass custom link you need to create **mixin of payment.js**

Follow below steps for add link in payment steps when no payment methods available :

> **1)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/payment.html': 
                'RH_CustomCheckout/template/payment.html' //override payment.html file
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
                'RH_CustomCheckout/js/view/payment-mixin': true // Create mixin of payment.js to add custom link
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> **2)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li id="payment" role="presentation" class="checkout-payment-method" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div id="checkout-step-payment"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content"
         role="tabpanel"
         aria-hidden="false">
        <!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->
        <form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
                </legend><br />
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
                     <!-- ko if: (!isPaymentMethodsAvailable()) -->
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'No Payment method available.'"></span>
                    <b><a data-bind="i18n: 'click here', attr: { href: getCustomerAccountUrl() }" target="_new"></a></b>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'to edit address.'"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

> **3)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/url'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    quote,
    stepNavigator,
    paymentService,
    methodConverter,
    getPaymentInformation,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    $t,
    url
) {
    'use strict';
    var mixin = {
        getCustomerAccountUrl: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.customUrl; // Get URL from Block file
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

To pass URL from **block/helper** ,You have to just override **getConfig()** function of **CompositeConfigProvider.php** file.

> **4)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- pass custom data to checkout page -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout_custom_payment_block" xsi:type="object">RH\CustomCheckout\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **5)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace RH\CustomCheckout\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface {
    protected $customCheckout;

    public function __construct(
        \RH\CustomCheckout\Block\CustomBlock $customCheckout
    ) {
        $this->customCheckout = $customCheckout;
    }
    public function getConfig() {
        $config = [];
        $config['customUrl'] = $this->customCheckout->getCustomerAccountURL();
        return $config;
    }
}
```

> **6)** app/code/RH/CustomCheckout/Block/CustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace RH\CustomCheckout\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getCustomerAccountURL() {
        return 'customer account url which you want to add';
    }
}
?>
```

---

If you want to add this custom URL into your theme's checkout **payment.html** file. Then, you just need to replace this below code in your html file. and no need to override payment.html file from **requirejs-config.js**. So, remove **payment.html** override code from **requirejs-config.js [Step 1]** if you want to access that data in your theme's checkout **payment.html**

Replace this below div in your theme's **payment.html** file :

**From :**

```
<div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
    <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**To :**

```
<div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
     <!-- ko if: (!isPaymentMethodsAvailable()) -->
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'No Payment method available.'"></span>
    <b><a data-bind="i18n: 'click here', attr: { href: getCustomerAccountUrl() }" target="_new"></a></b>
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'to edit address.'"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

---

**Output :**

[image]
Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan. It was very clear and nice explanation!!.

Comment: Happy coding !! :) +1 for acceptance

Answer (score 1):

You can create one function in `payment.js` file using this way

Create `requirejs-config.js` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is..

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/payment-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now you need to create one `payment-mixin.js` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment-mixin.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/url'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    quote,
    stepNavigator,
    paymentService,
    methodConverter,
    getPaymentInformation,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    $t,
    url
) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/payment'
        },
        getBaseUrl: function () {
            /*You can add your URL here.*/
            return url.build('customer/account');
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

I've created `getBaseUrl()` function here in this `mixin` file and also override template file from `Magento_Checkout/payment` to `Vendor_Module/payment`.

So now we need to create one template file here in our custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html

Content for this file is

```
<li id="payment" role="presentation" class="checkout-payment-method" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div id="checkout-step-payment"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content"
         role="tabpanel"
         aria-hidden="false">
        <!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->
        <form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
                </legend><br />
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }"><b>click here</b> to edit address</a>
                </div>
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've called that function in this html template file.

Hope this will work for you!